# How to Paste Data from API into Select Dropdownlist

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
A select dropdownlist containing data from api.
Label is first and last name and value is email.

Problem:
I do not know how to connect the data from api and paste it into select dropdownlist.

What part am I missing?

Info:
I'm newbie in reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bz1o1u

Thank you!

Comment: its in this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3Px88x_PsA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to transform your data to `react-select` options props shape.

```
fetch(`...`)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(
            data => {
            //here
             data.map(item=>this.setState({options:[...this.state.options,{value:item.id,label: item.username}] }))
            )
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

then pass to component

```
 <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.state.options}
      />
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-nnbyi)

Comment: "              ...this.state.options," what is the purpose to use "..."?

Comment: `options` is a state variable, we use it as data-source for `react-select`

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using `hooks` instead of React `Classes`, as of 2020 they pretty much feel like the future of React ( this is coming from someone with extensive experience in both `Classes` and `hooks` )

**Notice:** I have harcoded the api query string since I found the code organization to be more complicated than it needs to be.

These are the contents of **index.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom"
import './style.css';
import Select from 'react-select';

function List() {
  // The default value for the option list
  const [itemList, setList] = useState([]);
  // Initialize state for the selected item as null
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);

  // similar to componentDidMount but varies slightly in execution
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://randomuser.me/api?results=7&nat=us"
        );
        const responseJson = await response.json()

        // Map the list according the the react-select api
        const parsedList = responseJson.results && responseJson.results.map(({name,id}) => {

          return{
            value: id.value,
            label: `${name.first} ${name.last}`
          }
        })

        setList(parsedList);
      } catch (err) {
        // Errors Are logged here
        console.log(err, "API ERROR");
      }
    }
    // Call the function here
    getData();
  }, []);

  function handleChange(selectedItem) {
    // Handle selected item here
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedItem);
    // Change state
    setItem(selectedItem);
  }
  return <Select value={item} onChange={handleChange} options={itemList} />;
}

render(<List />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

you can render the List as any react component ie . `<List/>`

Comment: "I highly suggest using hooks instead of React Classes," Thank you for help  and I will keep it in my mind about it.